# How to encode image in webassembly like base64

Tags: webassembly

Is there a way to encode images inside webassembly code?

So instead of loading an image inside a canvas which is drawn with Wasm but to encode the image inside the code.

Something similar to using base64 images but then in the compiled wasm code instead of base64 where we can just load it in a new tab and then save it as an image.

Maybe doing something like drawing pixel-by-pixel. 
However one of the restriction is that it cannot get to big in size as for downloading speed.

Comment: Are you using Emscripten? What kind of language do you use for WASM?

Comment: Hi yes we use emscripten and language is C or c++. We could switch to other languages if needed.

Comment: I found it a bit confusing what you want to achive and what "encode" means. So do you mean you want to embed images files into WASM at compile time, or to create HTML image elements instead of drawing them on a canvas? Besides no matter what you do downloading speed matters because you cannot load an image from nowhere.

Comment: @BumsikKim, the idea is to display some images and text using wasm/C/emscripten. For rendering the image and text we use SDL2. 
However the for a simple image and a bit of text the WASM file is already more then 1 MB. Also the image is then loaded on the side as base64 image which increases the total download size even more. So with "encode" I probably should have used rendering from the WASM binary.

Comment: I looked up image to C array and found this online: https://littlevgl.com/image-to-c-array however a 350kb image turns into a 22MB C file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to make your question to clear, it seems like you want to use image files on wasm but don't want to the binary size impact due to wasm binary encoding.

In that case, why don't you pack them as a separate file and then pass it to wasm? Emscripten offers [a virtual file system](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html) that supports [pre-loading files](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/files/packaging_files.html#).

Suppose your image file is `your_image.png`, by adding [`--preload-file`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-preload-file) option to emcc you can ship them. As a packed file outside of wasm binary. For example:

```
$ emcc \
    your_source_file.cpp \
    --preload-file your_asset_dir/your_image.png \
    ...other emcc options...
```

Will create `.bin` file that contains `your_image.png` (and other files if you add more), as well as compiled `.wasm`, `.js` files. This `.bin` file should be much more space-efficient than hard-coding the binary on C. Your wasm (precisely, the JS file that loads the wasm module) will download the `.bin` file at run-time.

And you can open the file just like an ordinary file on local filesystem:

```
// I think UNIX open() will also work.
FILE *file = fopen("your_image.png", "r");
```

For more detail on this feature go to Emscripten's [tutorial](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#using-files).